# Can we get the information on the number of items in the review queues back, so we can see at a glance how much is up for review?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Several months ago, SE changed the format of the stuff on the top line. I got used to the new format, including the hamburger, except for one thing:

The old format told me at a glance how many items were in each review queue without my having to click on anything. Yes, I am lazy, but I can be **guilted** into reviewing if I see at a glance that there are 100 close votes to review.  If the heading doesn't tell me that there is content to review, I feel much less guilty about skipping the queues.

Can we get the info-at-a-glance back?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there is no reason to remove the number. I'd like to know how much of an impact my reviewing will have.

Comment: I for one bookmark a site's review page instead of the homepage (if I'm a reviewer on the site). So whenever I visit, I'm first taken to the queues, and then from there, I decide whether or not I should move on to the question pages. So, the review queue link in the top bar, whether number or dot, is Fredo to me.

Comment: @NVZ some questions are so low quality, it takes seconds to decide on their "fate" but it seems you might cast to close a question without seeing whether any answers have been posted.   I know I have a better idea when I see questions and answers on an entire page.

Comment: @ab2  I like not seeing a red number giving me an unnecessary guilt trip. If I want to review I will, and I do.

Comment: The number bore only a passing resemblance to the *actual* number of available reviews. SE fixed that problem by making sure that it's never incorrect because it's never shown.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see where you are getting at. I _can_ and I _do_ visit any questions page even while I'm reviewing, _when_ I feel like more context would help..

Comment: It seemed from your comment you jumped straight into the review queue. Apologies @NVZ

Comment: @Mari-LouA Of course, I jump to the review queues, but I look into a post's context and the entire question page when a question or answer I'm reviewing requires it of me. There's always a way to go to the actual question page _from_ the reviews.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a change peculiar to our site; it’s a [network-wide change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/153355). You might want to read in more detail how it’s now supposed to work.

If you really want to see the number, simply click the “all queues” link in the toolbar’s popup menu for the review queues.

Comment: Or a middle click on the review icon takes one directly to the "all queues".